# detect boxes/tables and remove them

Tags: c++, opencv

How to remove all vertical and horizontal lines that form boxes/tables

I have searched and tried.. But can't make it work

Have tried to search for it the last couple of days.. have found a few examples which doesn't work.. Have tried to get the pieces together..

```
cv:Mat img = cv::imread(input, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

cv::Mat grad;
cv::Mat morphKernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(3, 3));
cv::morphologyEx(img, grad, cv::MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);

cv::Mat res;
cv::threshold(grad, res, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);

// find contours
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(res.size(), CV_8UC1);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(res, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    cv::Mat approx;
    double peri = cv::arcLength(contours[i], true);
    cv::approxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, 0.04 * peri, true);
    int num_vertices = approx.rows;

    if(num_vertices == 4){
        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);

        // this is a rectangle
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MORPH_ELLIPSE ?? How big is contours.size?

Comment: it depends on how many contours it finds

Comment: Who down votes without comment?  What’s up with that?

Comment: ?? On the image displayed EXACTLY how many is that?  0?  14,005?  Add an output statement before the for loop.

Comment: 14 boxes/rectangles

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this issue. Can you provide the specific `#include`s you used?

Comment: have updated my question with all includes.. not all are used

Comment: I'm getting a whole ton of compilation errors. Which OpenCV version are you using?  Note: can see in at least one 2014 posting `( CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE is from the outdated [and now removed] cv api )`  Today is 2019.

Comment: I use `OpenCV 3.2.0`

Comment: Have now upgraded to `3.4.1` and still don't get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that :

- threshold your image
- compute connected components
- remove particules for which at least 3 of 4 bounding box tops are in touch with particule

This should give you something like that :
[image: result]

Here is the associated source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <limits>

using namespace cv;

struct BBox {

    BBox() :
        _xMin(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()),
        _xMax(std::numeric_limits<int>::min()),
        _yMin(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()),
        _yMax(std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
    {}

    int _xMin;
    int _xMax;
    int _yMin;
    int _yMax;
};

int main()
{
    // read input image
    Mat inputImg = imread("test3_1.tif", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // create binary image
    Mat binImg;
    threshold(inputImg, binImg, 254, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    // compute connected components
    Mat labelImg;
    const int nbComponents = connectedComponents(binImg, labelImg, 8, CV_32S);

    // compute associated bboxes
    std::vector<BBox> bboxColl(nbComponents);
    for (int y = 0; y < labelImg.rows; ++y) {

        for (int x = 0; x < labelImg.cols; ++x) {

            const int curLabel = labelImg.at<int>(y, x);
            BBox& curBBox = bboxColl[curLabel];
            if (curBBox._xMin > x)
                curBBox._xMin = x;
            if (curBBox._xMax < x)
                curBBox._xMax = x;
            if (curBBox._yMin > y)
                curBBox._yMin = y;
            if (curBBox._yMax < y)
                curBBox._yMax = y;
        }
    }

    // parse all labels
    std::vector<bool> lutTable(nbComponents);
    for (int i=0; i<nbComponents; ++i) {

        // check current label width
        const BBox& curBBox = bboxColl[i];
        if (curBBox._xMax - curBBox._xMin > labelImg.cols * 0.3)
            lutTable[i] = false;
        else
            lutTable[i] = true;
    }

    // create output image
    Mat resImg(binImg);
    MatConstIterator_<int> iterLab = labelImg.begin<int>();
    MatIterator_<unsigned char> iterRes = resImg.begin<unsigned char>();
    while (iterLab != labelImg.end<int>()) {

        if (lutTable[*iterLab] == true)
            *iterRes = 1;
        else
            *iterRes = 0;

        ++iterLab;
        ++iterRes;
    }

    // write result
    imwrite("resImg3_1.tif", resImg);
}
```

I simply remove all labels for which with is greater than 30% of image total width. Your image is quite noisy so I can't use bounding box tops touches as said before, sorry...

Don't know if this will match with all your images but you could add some geometrical filters to improve this first version.

Regards,

Comment: would it also be possible to add some straight line detection just to make sure it doesn't filter out other contents in the image? :)

Comment: Have added one more test image where a line (underlined text) intersect with the text `DKK 597,00` (the comma) and the removal of the lines should not delete parts of the text :)

Comment: Thanks for the example :) but when I try to compile the code I get alot of errors.. for instance `BBox` was not declared in this scope.. Have tried to put `cv::` namespace in front of it.. Could you please be explicit in your code and type the namespaces for the variables/objects like `cv::Mat` etc

Comment: I use opencv `3.4.1`

Comment: Thanks for the whole code :) but I might have found a solution to remove the noise. Could you post both the solution you already have posted and the other solution with "bounding box tops touches" ? So I can test which one works best :)

Comment: I you just have to check label image value at bounding box tops using something like that : "labelImg.at<int>(curBBox._yMin, curBBox._xMinx);" and count number equality with curLabel value. If you get 3 or more equality set lubTable[curLabel] = false. Note that this will remove all occurences of 'I' charactere. Perhaps adding pixel count for each label and filter small area would be a good idea.

Comment: Have just copy pasted your code.. It outputs a pitch black image

Comment: Hi, output image contains binary data which means that you only will have 0 and 1 values in image. Image viewer usually output this kind of images with a range from 0 to 255. Try to replace *iterRes = 1; by *iterRes = 255; and you should see expected result

Comment: ok thanks.. I'm not that familiar with either opencv or c++.. It seems to work great :)

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code.. Why do you do this? `threshold(inputImg, binImg, 254, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);` it will just output a pitch black image (no viewable objects).. and you are doing `connectedComponents` on this image...

Comment: This operation does the following operation
if inputImg(y,x) <= 254, binImg(y,x)=1
else binImg(y, x)=0

Comment: But I don't understand how you can detect any components on a completely black image?

Comment: In my case, output image is not black -> valued to 1 when input image value is not equal to 255 and 0 otherwise. You do not have the same behavior ?

Comment: I have another question.. is each pixel represented in each `lutTable[i]` ??

Comment: and how to get each contour from each component (bbox)? I want to validate the shape of each structure

Comment: lutTable is used to select particles shapes which will be keeped in output image.
Size of this table is equal to number of labels in image not to number of pixels.
If lutTable[i] != 0 then we keep label with id 'i'

Comment: If you want to work with contours you have to use findContours function. In case of your "tekni-fi" image noise has to be filtered since it leads to more than 65535 different shapes. Using contours was my first idea but it doesn't seems to be usable in case of "tekni-fi" image whitout previous filtering. Note that findContours function can be parametered in several way, you will find some examples of usage in opencv manual (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a).

Comment: If it become to hard for you I could, if wished, make you a quote for a full developpement. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LineSegmentDetector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#linesegmentdetector) for this purpose:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("image.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# This is the detector, you might have to play with the parameters
lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0, _scale=0.6)

lines, widths, _, _ = lsd.detect(gray)

if lines is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        l = lines[i][0]
        # Much slower version of Euclidean distance
        if np.sqrt((l[0]-l[2])**2 + (l[1]-l[3])**2) > 50:
            # You might have to tweak the threshold as well for other images
            cv2.line(image, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (255, 255, 255), 3, 
                     cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", image)
```

Output:

[image: Result]

[image: Result]

As you can see, the lines *aren't completely* removed in the top image so I am leaving the *tweaking* part to you. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use this answer box to make a few comments.

First off, its way easier to see progress, if you can easily see what the output looks like visually.  With that in mind, here is an update to your code with an emphasis on viewing interim results.  I'm using [VS Studio Community 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/), and [OpenCV version 4.0.1](https://opencv.org/releases.html) (64bit) in Win10 for anyone who wants to repeat this exercise. There were a few routines used that required updates for OpenCV 4...

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{    
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("0zx9Q.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );        // --> Contour size = 0x000000e7 hex (231 each)
    // cv::Mat img = cv::imread("0zx9Q.png", cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2); // --> Contour size = 0x00000068 hex (104 each)
    // cv::Mat img = cv::imread("0zx9Q.png", cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4); // --> Contour size = 0x0000001f hex (31 each)
    // cv::Mat img = cv::imread("0zx9Q.png", cv::IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_8); // --> Contour size = 0x00000034 hex (52 each)

    if (!img.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // cv::namedWindow("Display Window - GrayScale Image", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);   // Create a window for display.
    // cv::imshow("Display Window - GrayScale Image", img);                      // Show our image inside it.
    // cv::waitKey(0);                                                           // Wait for a keystroke in the window

    cv::Mat imgOriginal = cv::imread("0zx9Q.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    cv::namedWindow("Display Window of Original Document", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);   // Create a window for display.

    cv::Mat grad;
    cv::Mat morphKernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(25, 25));
    // MORPH_ELLIPSE, contourSize: 0x00000005    when 60,60... but way slow...
    // MORPH_ELLIPSE, contourSize: 0x00000007    when 30,30...  
    // MORPH_ELLIPSE, contourSize: 0x00000007    when 20,20... 
    // MORPH_ELLIPSE, contourSize: 0x0000000a    when 15,15...
    // MORPH_ELLIPSE, contourSize: 0x0000007a    when 5,5...
    // MORPH_ELLIPSE, contourSize: 0x000000e7    when 3,3 and IMREAD_GRAYSCALE 
    // MORPH_CROSS,   contourSize: 0x0000008e    when 5,5 
    // MORPH_CROSS,   contourSize: 0x00000008    when 25,25 
    // MORPH_RECT,    contourSize: 0x00000007    when 25,25 

    cv::morphologyEx(img, grad, cv::MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);

    cv::Mat res;
    cv::threshold(grad, res, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);

    // find contours
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(res.size(), CV_8UC1);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(res, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    int contourSize = contours.size();
    std::cout << " There are a total of " << contourSize << " contours. \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < contourSize; i++) {
        cv::Mat approx;
        double peri = cv::arcLength(contours[i], true);
        cv::approxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, 0.04 * peri, true);
        int num_vertices = approx.rows;
        std::cout << " Contour # " << i << " has " << num_vertices << " vertices.\n";
        if (num_vertices == 4) {
            cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
            cv::rectangle(imgOriginal, rect, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("Display Window of Original Document", imgOriginal);           // Show our image inside it.
    cv::waitKey(0);                                                           // Wait for a keystroke in the window
}
```

With that said, the parameters for `getStructuringElement()` matter huge.  I spent a lot of time trying different choices, with very mixed results.  And it turns out there are a whole lot of `findContours()` responses that don't have four vertices.  I suspect the whole `findContours()` approach is probably flawed.  I often would get false rectangles identified around text characters in words and phrases.  Additionally the lighter lines surrounding some boxed areas would be ignored.

[image: Highlighted Rectangles within original document]

Instead, I think I'd be looking hard at straight line detection, [via techniques discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv), if such a response exists for a C++ and not python. Perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476410/opencv-c-line-detection-with-houghlinesp), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378722/opencv-line-detection)? I hoping line detection techniques would ultimately get better results.  And hey, if the documents / images selected always include a white background, it would be pretty easy to solid rectangle them OUT of the image, via `LineTypes: cv::FILLED`

Info here provided, not as an answer to the posted question but as a methodology to visually determine success in the future.